# How do I create an MSTest project in a .NET console application

Tags: .net, mstest

How can I insert a MSTest project in a .NET C# console project. My idea was to create a console project as a solution and create a mstest project in it.
[My directory structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ge0C.jpg).

Starting from this structure, I added the test project to the solution using the `dotnet sln add TestProject\TestProject.csproj` command.

Next I gave the test project a reference to the main project with `dotnet add TestProject\TestProject.csproj reference ConsoleProject\ConsoleProject.csproj`

In the TestProject directory, the dotnet test command fails. The error message is: `CS0579: Duplicate attribute "System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute [...ConsoleProject.sln]`

the project is running in a .NET7 environment. I am working with Visual Studio Code 1.82.0 and the extension C# Dev Kit in version v0.4.10.